# Is there a more compact regex for this lookbehind?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to select every occurrence of 4 leading spaces on each line of a file to replace them with 2 spaces in order to reformat. The Find All regex I ended up using was:

```
^ {4}|(?<=^ {4}) {4}|(?<=^ {8}) {4}|(?<=^ {12}) {4}|(?<=^ {16}) {4}
```

I've made [a demo here](https://www.regex101.com/r/eF5xE7/1) showing exactly how I expect it to highlight the file.

Is there a better way of achieving this? Note I want Sublime Text to individually select each group of 4 spaces, I don't want each line containing leading white-space to be all in one selection.

Comment: How about using [`\G` to glue](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) matches to start of line, [see demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yX5vQ2/1). Actually this wouldn't require a lookbehind but without intrestingly requires [much more steps](https://regex101.com/r/xN0pV0/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^(?:(  )  )(?:(  )  )?(?:(  )  )?(?:(  )  )?` replace with `\1\2\3\4`

Is functionally equivalent and doesn't require lookbehind.

It requires about 9% of the effort for the regex engine as well (702 vs 7680 steps).